# JSP/JSTL - Unable to display information to the browser

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

**Background:**

I wrote a previous servlet that created dynamic webpages where it would read and write to a MySQL database. When I would read from it, I stored the result in a ResultSet, then displayed this information. Everything worked and I was told I should re-write it using JSPs and JSTLs. To do this, in my servlet, I created a ResultSet and stored each column's result in a separate ArrayList. In my JSP, I'm trying to iterate through the ArrayLists, however, the webpage is blank. Since I'm using NetBeans, it normally will indicate any errors, but there seem to be none, so I'm guessing there's either a logical error or a run-time error (which doesn't exactly narrow it down). I've tried simply printing the size of an ArrayList but even that isn't displaying! My guess is either the ArrayList is never populated or it's not properly being sent to the JSP.

To note, my database is populated and I am able to write to it. I've looked throughout various websites to see if anything can help but nothing has so far. I also went through my lecture notes and my syntax seems to be correct.

As part of the assignment, we are required to write all servlet code in processRequest(request, response). doPost and doGet both call this method.

**My Servlet:**

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {    
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    ResultSet res = null;
    ArrayList<String> bookIDs, bookTitles, bookAuthors;
    DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
    try {
        res = BookDB.showBooks();
        bookIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
        bookTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
        bookAuthors = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(res.next()) {
            bookIDs.add(res.getString("bookID"));
            bookTitles.add(res.getString("title"));
            bookAuthors.add(res.getString("author"));
        }
        request.setAttribute("IDHolder", bookIDs);
        request.setAttribute("titlesHolder", bookTitles);
        request.setAttribute("authorHolder", bookAuthors);
        RequestDispatcher booksDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("jspShowAll.jsp");
        booksDispatcher.forward(request, response); 
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        Logger.getLogger(ShowAllBooks.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqle);
    } catch (IOException iox) {
        Logger.getLogger(ShowAllBooks.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, iox);
    } catch (ServletException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ShowAllBooks.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
```

**ResultSet Creation (in a separate package):**

```
public static ResultSet showBooks() throws SQLException {         
    ConnControl myConnPool=new ConnControl();
    Statement s=null;
    ResultSet res=null;
    Connection myConn=myConnPool.connect(); 
    String queryStm= "SELECT * FROM books;";
    s=myConn.createStatement();
    res = s.executeQuery(queryStm);
    return res;
}
```

This method was copied and pasted from my previous web app, which works perfectly. The table and database are the same.

**My JSP:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
</head>
<body>
    <c:forEach var="ids" items="${IDHolder}">
        <p>${ids}</p>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach var="titles" items="${titlesHolder}">
        <p>${titles}</p>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach var="authors" items="${authorHolder}">
        <p>${authors}</p>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

My Java Bean:

```
 public class Book {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public Book() {

    }

    public Book(int id, String title, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }  
    }
```

Comment: Did you get any exception?

Comment: @Masud that's the rub, it's a completely blank webpage. I'm not getting any exceptions of any sort. When I right-click on View Source, it too is blank (just did it as a hope there'd be something in there).

Comment: Check your logs. You probably have an exception, but since you catch it an log it, nothing is displayed in the page.

Comment: @JBNizet I removed the Logger.getLogger()... from my exceptions and replaced it with printStackTrace(). I found out I forgot to include the JSTL library.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the logs and calling printStackTrace() for each exception thrown, I found I overlooked the simplest thing. I forgot to include the JSTL library! Now that I did, I ran my JSP again and it displayed properly.